# Cocos2D-X nodes loading in wrong positions have RemoveAllChildren()

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm only using one scene object for my entire 2d sidescrolling platformer with two layers: There is a hudLayer for the controller, and the gameLayer for everything in the game.

When I control my character to walk into a door (sprite with a physicsBody that has a callback that takes me to the next level), the next level loads by these instructions:

- remove all event listeners
- stop all actions for both layers (the gameLayer typically has been doing a Follow action that follows the player, and is limited to the size of the backgroundSpriteNode)
- remove all children from the gameLayer
- set gameLayer position to Vec2(0,0)
- load level 2 (a complete copy of what level 1 should look like... load the background sprite to gameLayer, playerSprite, add event listeners)
- add event listeners back to the hudLayer

The only problem is that for whatever reason, the level only partially loads the way it should... For instance, coins appear in the spots they should, but platforms don't seem to. Neither that or the player, or other characters. Not sure really why these objects are specifically not loading in the correct positions, but maybe someone who has experienced this sort of problem before can help?

Most nodes (such as platforms) are appearing below the bottom of the screen when they should be fully shown at the bottom of the screen. Characters are appearing down there too when they should be appearing above the platforms.

P.S. After testing a bit more, I've come to realize that SOMETIMES some of the platforms are loading in the correct positions, but sometimes they aren't. Not sure why. A fix for this may be to load things one at a time with a delay between them. But I'd rather not have to put delays and just figure out what the deal is.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out: for whatever reason, I needed to add a delay in there. I think for whatever reason, by calling removeAllChildren(), something got messed up with the positions. It was my suspicion since SOME of the time, parts of the next level would load, but only some parts, and only sometimes.

Here's the code I added to run an action on the gameLayer once all children were removed, etc...

```
runAction(Sequence::createWithTwoActions(DelayTime::create(0.1), CallFunc::create( [&] ( ) {
            loadLevel2(this);
        })));
```